# Using mongodb's $and in php

Tags: php, mongodb, database

Setup, php + mongodb.

The database should contain multiple items where 'Title' contains both 'Apple' and 'Orange'. I am trying to obtain only the items that contain BOTH 'Apple' and 'Orange'.

```
  $regexOne = new MongoRegex( '/Apple/i' ); 
  $regexTwo = new MongoRegex('/Orange/i');

  $cursor = $collection->find( array( '$and' => array( array('Title' => $regexOne), array('Title' => $regexTwo) ) ) );
```

The same query with the '$and' replaced with a '$or' works correctly (or at least appears to), but this returns nothing despite there being data in the database that matches these conditions.

Comment: What happens if you run this query directly against MongoDB at the command line rather than through PHP?  Your title implies you think it's a PHP issue, but to me your problem sounds totally unrelated to PHP.  First step therefore is to eliminate PHP as a variable - if you see the same behavior talking directly to MongoDB, you know it's an issue with your query and has nothing to do with PHP; if you get the correct result at the command line, then it's a quirk with what you're sending through the PHP driver.

Comment: Sorry if my question was misleading I think I could have stated it better (and added more code perhaps). I have successfully managed to pull $and queries in the mongo shell, but I was having a problem translating it in into the php mongo syntax.

Comment: I have found the cause of the problem, I was using version 1.8 of mongodb, have now updated to the latest version and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing what [dimo414 said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743442/using-mongodbs-and-in-php#comment15587158_11743442), the first step is simply comparing Mongo's shell to PHP. Both of these are equivalent:

```
$ mongo 
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0-rc0
connecting to: test
> db.foo.drop()
true
> db.foo.insert({title:"apple"})
> db.foo.insert({title:"orange"})
> db.foo.insert({title:"apple orange"})
> db.foo.insert({title:"banana apple"})
> db.foo.insert({title:"banana plum"})
> db.foo.find({$and: [{title:/apple/i}, {title:/orange/i}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501804c4e7dc9abd7b58cd83"), "title" : "apple orange" }
> db.foo.find({$or: [{title:/apple/i}, {title:/orange/i}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501804bde7dc9abd7b58cd81"), "title" : "apple" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501804c0e7dc9abd7b58cd82"), "title" : "orange" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501804c4e7dc9abd7b58cd83"), "title" : "apple orange" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501804cce7dc9abd7b58cd84"), "title" : "banana apple" }
```

And in PHP (using [phpsh](http://www.phpsh.org/)):

```
php> $c = (new Mongo())->test->foo;

php> =iterator_to_array($c->find(['$and' => [['title' => new MongoRegex('/apple/i')], ['title' => new MongoRegex('/orange/i')]]]))
array(
  "501804c4e7dc9abd7b58cd83" => array(
    "_id" => <object #10 of type MongoId> {
      $id => "501804c4e7dc9abd7b58cd83",
    },
    "title" => "apple orange",
  ),
)

php> =iterator_to_array($c->find(['$or' => [['title' => new MongoRegex('/apple/i')], ['title' => new MongoRegex('/orange/i')]]]))
array(
  "501804bde7dc9abd7b58cd81" => array(
    "_id" => <object #11 of type MongoId> {
      $id => "501804bde7dc9abd7b58cd81",
    },
    "title" => "apple",
  ),
  "501804c0e7dc9abd7b58cd82" => array(
    "_id" => <object #12 of type MongoId> {
      $id => "501804c0e7dc9abd7b58cd82",
    },
    "title" => "orange",
  ),
  "501804c4e7dc9abd7b58cd83" => array(
    "_id" => <object #13 of type MongoId> {
      $id => "501804c4e7dc9abd7b58cd83",
    },
    "title" => "apple orange",
  ),
  "501804cce7dc9abd7b58cd84" => array(
    "_id" => <object #14 of type MongoId> {
      $id => "501804cce7dc9abd7b58cd84",
    },
    "title" => "banana apple",
  ),
)
```